# gnome-control-center sharing over SSH: core dumped

Tags: command-line, gnome, ssh, remote-desktop, gnome-control-center

I am logged onto a remote Ubuntu computer over SSH (using the `-Y` option. I am trying to enable screen sharing remotely, so I typed the command:

```
$ gnome-control-center sharing
```

And I got this error back:

```
double free or corruption (!prev)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Both computers are running Ubuntu 18.04. I did get this little line when I logged in with SSH:

```
/usr/bin/xauth:  file /home/(MY USERNAME HERE)/.Xauthority does not exist
```

How can I get gnome to work? If I can't, is there another way to enable screen sharing purely by the command line? Thank you so much!

Comment: have you tried the `-X` flag instead of `-Y`? also check the file permission and owner of `.Xauthority ` file. it should be user owned and permission should be 600 as I can see in my installation.